# How do I get the profile URL of a user?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, profile, theming

I want to create a custom view for profile pages, So I Want to get the profile URLs. Something like $node_url that get the profile URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) or [Profile 2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2)?

If not the URL looks like

```
www.example.com/username
www.example.com/user/UID.
```

Check the documentation about [Drupal paths and URL aliases](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/understanding-drupal/url-paths).